# Can't copy file on the same machine - Error 0x8007045D: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, windows-server-2008, copy-paste

[image: This picture sums up what I get]

I have Windows 2008 Server. In it I have 2 hard drives. One I use to store backup, I have it in the tray, which I turn on before backup and turn off after. I backup only virtual machines, my host is only used as that and nothing else.

One specific VHD file just doesn't want to copy to the other drive. But VM [with this file] works fine. Other VHD files go over fine. I even tried to zip it. It zipped, but I believe it was corrupted because zip was just over 1Gb from 45Gb original.

I tried `chkdsk` - it finds nothing on both drives.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally had downtime of my host and ran `chkdsk c: /F /R`. It ran scan when rebooted and fixed the issue with this file. Interestingly, `chkdsk` didn't report any issues when I ran it without `/F /R`.

Comment: I got that as well, I kept looking for solutions after chkdsk did not report anything.  Until I slapped my forehead and thought of the options that we used to use in the DOS days.

Comment: @RohitGupta Glad it helped